# How to manage a redirect request after a window.Open()

Tags: javascript

I am using `window.Open()` to call a controller action. This will cause the popup of view to happen. All works well except if session times out. If that happens a popup of the login screen appears.

```
var windowHandel = window.open( bla bla bla);
```

Using `windowHandel`, is there a way to see if I got the logon screen?

Answer (score 1):

This is generally easier to handle in the popup itself.  Rather than forwarding to the login screen directly, forward to a screen with some javascript which sets the location of window.opener (the original window) and then closes the popup.